# Querying into a Cube from View SQL Server using Laravel 6

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, ssas, oledb

I'm trying to access data to an SSAS CUBE server using SQL Server and Laravel (v.6), the problem is, using SQL Server interface when I called the view table it's working and no message error appears, when I try to call the same view table, I get the following error :

> SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Unable to initialize OLE DB provider data source object "MSOLAP" from the linked server "(null)"

The result in SQL Server shows no problem :

[image]

The Model from Laravel :

[image]

The controller call :

[image]

The error that I get from Laravel :

[image]

The View using OpenRawSet that contains the LinkedServer :

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you add the view and Linked Server definition?

Comment: done, the post is edited

Comment: Try connecting from a remote client with the same Windows Auth login used by the PHP application.  This may be a double-hop, requiring Kerberos configuration, or the Applciation's account may simply not have access to the AS Database.

Comment: i will test and give you a feedback , thank you

Comment: it's worked after changing the username connection from SQL  to Windows Authentification without setting up the username and password into Laravel  .env file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's worked after changing the connection from SQL Auth to Windows Authentification into Laravel,  by removing the username and password from .env file.

[image]

Thanks  David Browne for the light.